# how to calculate vwap price for a specified notional amount in kdb?

Tags: database, kdb

I have the following example table in kdb.

```
mkt:([] date:2018.05.05 2018.05.05 2018.05.05 2018.05.05; time:2018.05.05D01:30:00 2018.05.05D01:30:01 2018.05.05D01:30:01 2018.05.05D01:30:02; bid:((1.2110 1.21105);(1.2111 1.2109 1.2112);(1.2111 1.2109);(1.2110 1.21105)); bidSize:((3000000 1000000);(500000 1000000 1000000);(1000000 2000000);(1000000 1000000)); ask:((1.2111 1.21115);(1.2112 1.2110 1.2113);(1.2112 1.2110);(1.2111 1.21115)); askSize:((3000000 1000000);(500000 1000000 1000000);(1000000 2000000);(1000000 1000000)))
```

I have this as a solution but the numbers won't be the most accurate.

```
table:select date, time, bid:{x wavg y}'[bidSize;bid], bidSize: sum each bidSize, ask:{x wavg y}'[askSize;ask], askSize:sum each askSize from mkt
table: update cumulBidSize: sums bidSize, cumulAskSize: sums askSize from table
1#select from table where cumlBidSize>=5000000
```

I want to be able to have a function when given a specific size (e.g. 5000000), calculate the vwap for that size. How am I able to cycle through the data in the cell until i get 5000000?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to calculate the avg bid only for rows where the total bidSize is greater than or equal to a specified size:

`{[x]select {x wavg y}'[sum each bidSize;bid] from mkt where x<=sum each bidSize}[4000000]`

You can use this if you want to calculate the average price for only prices with an associate size greater than or equal to a specified size:

`{select bidSize wavg bid from ungroup mkt where bidSize>=x}[2000000]`

Hope this helps,

James

Comment: Hi James, thanks for you reply. I am actually trying to cycle through the bid prices and bidSize individually until I am satisfied (ie 5mio volume is achieved). However, the bid prices and bidSize are in a list in every row which makes it difficult.

Comment: Hi James. Will be trying this. I was just experimenting with ungroup. But your solution seems much better. As a favour, if you don't mind, I will keep you updated and hope to ask you further questions if need be? Finding help for kdb can be painful sometimes and hence the favour I am asking..

Comment: Hi Matthew - absolutely, no problem. To clarify my previous edit:
```{exec bid:deltas[x&sums bidSize]wavg bid, ask:deltas[x&sums askSize]wavg ask from y}[5000000](,')/[mkt]```

This uses over to flatten the rows of the table into a dictionary.The key part of the code is the use of deltas[limit&list] which allows us to calculate how much each bidSize contributed to the total, use this as our weighting for wavg. By using using 'limit' we will only use up to this size as a portion of the total size. We use only half of the penultimate size, and none of the last size as they exceed our limit.

Comment: @JamesBurrows Nice, this comment above should be promoted as the correct answer (not the original answer)! Though I don't see why you can't use ungroup instead of appending over

Comment: Terrtlynch, could you elaborate further on how you would use ungroup?

Comment: Hi James, could you explain the [5000000](,')/[mkt] part? I understand that x is 5e6 and y is mkt. 
Is [5000000](,')/[mkt] the same as 5000000,'/mkt?
Trying to understand this part.

Comment: ```(,')/[mkt]``` will flatten the the table, similar to ```ungroup``` but distinct in that it creates a dictionary of column keys to list values whereas ungroup flattens nesting into a table. As such this will work for nested lists of differing lengths whereas ungroup would fail with a ```'length``` error.

You could replace this with ungroup however, if you were sure your lists would be of the same length consistently:

```{exec bid:deltas[x&sums bidSize]wavg bid, ask:deltas[x&sums askSize]wavg ask from y}[5000000;ungroup mkt]```

Comment: @matthew.j James elaborated on my ungroup comment above. The ungrouped mkt table could be fed into the function rather than feeding in a flattened dictionary of the form `(,')/[mkt]`. Ungrouped table is cleaner in my opinion